# Passing ASP.NET Session Variables to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, session-variables

Here is all the code that should be necessary,

inside a function i create a control, either a text box radio button list etc.  once the control is created, i put it in a panel then do the following:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        panel.RenderControl(hw);
        Session["formHTML"] = sb.ToString();
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

the Label1 text comes out perfectly.  it is exactly what it should be, which is the html of the panel that I get from the panel.RenderControl(hw) line.  Here is my problem. on a button click I have:

```
    Response.Redirect("~/preview.aspx");
```

and here is the code on my preview.aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function preview() {
        var html =  '<%= Session["formHTML"]%>';
        alert(html);
        $('#previewForm').empty();
        $('#previewForm').append(html);
    }
</script>

<body onload="preview()">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div id="previewForm">
      </div>
   </form>
</body>
```

my problem is the session variable being passed to the function.  it will not do the alert in my function.  now i have another session variable, `Session["formID"]`.  when i put the `Session[FormID]` in my javascript function instead of `Session["formHTML"]`, it works perfectly.  if the ID is 434, that appends to the div tag i indicated.  now formHTML has HTML as a string.  for some reason it does not like this.  I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  Uncaught
>
> ReferenceError: preview is not defined

I cannot figure this out, i am not sure why it doesnt work.  inside my javascript function I have tried:

```
        var html =  '<%= Session["formHTML"].ToString()%>';
```

and

```
        var html =  "'" + '<%= Session["formHTML"]%>' + "'";
```

i only tried these because i figured the html was not being rendered as a string properly in javascript.  i clearly do not know why i am getting this error, which is why i dont have any ideas on how to fix it.

for the comments:

ok, so when my function looks like this: var html = '<% Session["formHTML"] %>  it renders as:

```
        function preview() {
            var html =  '<div id="panel0" class="panelHeader" class="box ui-draggable" data-ui-widget="draggable">
    <span id="mylabel">mylabel</span><span id="lbl0" onclick="deleteControl(panel0)" style="color:Red;">x</span>
</div>';
            alert(html);
            $('#previewForm').empty();
            $('#previewForm').append(html);
        }
```

which looks right to me, but still produces the error

Comment: Are you getting that error on the JavaScript console?  If the error is happening in JavaScript, show the actual JavaScript that gets rendered to the page.  The server-side code doesn't help with that.

Comment: im not sure what you are asking me for.  i mean the function works with a session variable that doesnt contain html.  when i use the session variable that has the html i get the  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Uncaught  errors.  i dont know what else you are asking me to show you

ReferenceError: preview is not defined

Comment: Well, for starters, where do you get that error?  In server-side code or client-side code?  If it's in client-side code then you'll need to show us what's actually running on the client side.  `var html =  "'" + '<%= Session["formHTML"]%>' + "'";` is what you have on the server, but that's not what the JavaScript executes.  We need to see what's rendered to the client in the JavaScript code in order to determine why there's an error.  Clearly it sounds like you're rendering something to the page that isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: please see the original question, i added to the bottom so the code looks appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may also be that your HTML has unescaped illegal characters that is throwing off your string values. '"/\

So....

I would make sure that I escape and unescape them in the handoff. There are best practices on that as well. I am assuming that that ASP.net is buffering the output when you set it to the value of the label, but when you set it to JS directly you get the conflict.

Also, We use

```
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "set_campaign", "$(document).ready(function(){  setCampaignID(" + Request.QueryString["campaign_id"] + ");});", true);
```

To insert script into the page, instead of <% tags %>. Tags will work fine, but used incorrectly can cause problems with unset values and inexperienced programmers, versus injecting it into working script with no dependencies. Like the challenges that you are facing now.

You can also replace an asp:literal, but I like the startup script better and I think reflects your needs

Cheers!